# Difference between android automotive and android auto

Tags: android, android-auto, android-automotive

What´s the difference between android auto and android automotive?

https://www.android.com/intl/en_en/auto/

https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/

Answer (score 10):

Android Auto is powered by a smartphone using an application. The application can be run on the phone, or by plugging the phone into an Android auto compatible head unit. The phone then "projects" an interface onto the cars head unit, giving access to maps/waze, phone calls, play music/compatible apps. It even has an OEM app segment, although most of the time that just takes the user out of android auto and back to the cars interface.

Android Automotive is instead run on a computer in the vehicle, and is a full android OS experience rather than an extension of the phone. Android Automotive can control HVAC and some other car systems depending on the implementation by the cars manufacturer. It doesn't require a smartphone to be plugged in, while still giving a similar experience to android auto.

https://arstechnica.com/cars/2017/05/android-automotive-hands-on-google-is-finally-ready-to-talk-about-its-car-os/

Answer (score 5):

Android Auto is an application for smartphone integration. All the data is rendered on the smartphone and mirorrored on the head-unit of the vehicle. There is no possiblity to use Android Auto in the car without smartphones. Additionally Android Auto is not able to influence vehicle functions.

Android Automotive is an open source project by Google which runs native on the head-unit of the vehicle. It is the connected-car-platform of the vehicle like mercedes me connect in Mercedes Banz vehicles. With Android Automotive it is possible to contrll vehicle functions and remote services. No smartphone is needed. One of the first cars equipped with Android Automotive is the Polestar 2 launching in 2020. One big advantage of Android Automotive is that OEMs are able to adapt the design layout to the brand specific UI.

Answer (score 1):

Android Automotive is a car system that cantain radio,audio,video and so on.
Android Auto:use the phone to connect the car displya with usb,then you can run the phone's apps onto he cars head unit.

Answer (score -1):

Android Auto is an app that our smartphone can be operate by the headunit on the car. So, you just plug the USB cable to headunit then easily manage to open any app on your phone directly from the headunit screen.

Android Automotive is an app or maybe an operating system for car headunit system that can access or managing android application on the device. Like our phone on the headunit without owning the real smartphone.