# Issue while importing android.car package

Tags: android, obd-ii, iot-for-automotive, android-automotive

I am trying to import an android.car package, but it's not showing up.

I can hardly find any useful tutorial to do so. Looks like I'm missing out something really elementary.

If someone can guide in a step by step way. I will be really thankful.

Reference : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/package-summary

Is there a way to use the Android automotive library?

Any other free opensource library to help me try my hand at On Board Diagnostics?

Thanks,

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/auto/start

Comment: As per this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46091332/difference-between-android-automotive-and-android-auto Both Android Auto and Android Automotive are different. So we are looking out for Android Automotive, that is to access the On Board diagnostics

Comment: Android Automotive SDK for Android Q is now released. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125921